# Binding the value of a variable to a text input

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding, textinput

I've been looking all over the internet but I couldn't find an answer to the following question: Is it possible to have the value of some string variable bound to the text inside a text input control? To clarify, whatever text was entered into the text input would be stored as the value of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Simply enough, you can do 2 way binding:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
  [Bindable] private var someObject:Object;
  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput text="@{someObject.someString}" />
```

With 2 way binding, any changes to the property 'someString' will change the TextInput or if you change the TextInput manually, your property 'someString' will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but you could always have an event handler on the `focusLost`event from the textInput which sets the variable you want to the textInput.text

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of the variable using the `change` event of the `TextInput`.

**Example** (untested):

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
  [Bindable] public var someText:String = "foo";

  protected function myText_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
  {
    someText = myText.text;
  }
  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput id="myText" text="{someText}" change="myText_changeHandler(event)" />
```